# How to cycle through Firefox tabs "normally"?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I reinstalled Firefox, version 63, and now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> don't work to cycle through existing tabs. If I open Firefox and open a second tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does nothing, and I expected it to return to the first tab. If I hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keys, I have a thumbnail preview of Firefox tabs, as in this picture:

[image: Firefox menu of tab cycling]

How can I get the "normal" behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sounds like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
is using the recently used order. 
You can change settings by going to the “Options” page
by one of the following procedures:

- type “about:preferences” into the address bar
- click on the “hamburger” (≣) and select “Options” from the menu
- select “Options” from the “Tools” menu

and then, in “General” → “Tabs”,
uncheck “Ctrl+Tab cycles through tabs in recently user order”.